# How to automatically set Maven compiler plugin based on $JAVA_HOME env variable?

Tags: environment-variables, maven-3, java-home, maven-compiler-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.2.3.  I have a multi-module project and currently have my Maven compiler plugin set as such

```
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <source>1.6</source>
                                    <target>1.6</target>
                                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                                    <fork>true</fork>
                                    <!-- <debug>true</debug> <debuglevel>none</debuglevel> -->
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <id>default-testCompile</id>
                                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

What I am wondering is how can I set the compiler version based on the $JAVA_HOME variable in my system, meaning, if $JAVA_HOME points at a Java 6 installation, my Maven compiler will use “1.6” as its source and target.  Similarly, if my $JAVA_HOME points at a Java 7 installation, source and target would be “1.7” and so on.  If there is no $JAVA_HOME set in the environment, I’d like the compiler to default to 1.6.

Thanks for advice and examples regarding how to set this up.

Comment: This is simply not possible and does not make sense, cause your build would be environment dependent. Best is to define the source/target level in your build as you already did. Furthermore you should use the [maven-enforcer-plugin to force which JDK is used](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html). Apart from that if you have not JAVA_HOME set you can build cause a JDK is needed to run Maven.

Comment: The build would not be environemtn depednent, I'm just looking for a way to compile my source code based on what the $JAVA_HOME var is set to without having to hard-code versions within my pom.  Not possible?  Come on, man.  All things are possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jarrod pointed, solution is usage of [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Using example provided from maven docs.

> Profiles can be automatically triggered based on the detected state of
>   the build environment. These triggers are specified via an
>    section in the profile itself. Currently, this detection
>   is limited to prefix-matching of the JDK version, the presence of a
>   system property or the value of a system property. Here are some
>   examples.
>
> The following configuration will trigger the profile when the JDK's
>   version starts with "1.4" (eg. "1.4.0_08", "1.4.2_07", "1.4"):

See example below merged with your example and maven doc example.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
    <activation>
      <jdk>1.6</jdk>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <!-- <debug>true</debug> <debuglevel>none</debuglevel> -->
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                            <execution>
                                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                            </execution>
                    </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Guide to building for different environments using Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html)

Building the same artifact for different environments has always been an annoyance. You have multiple environments, for instance test and production servers or, maybe a set of servers that run the same application with different configurations. In this guide I'll explain how you can use profiles to build and package artifacts configured for specific environments. See [Introduction to Build Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for a more in-depth explanation of the profile concept.

Comment: Still not making the logical leap here -- how would the way in which my $JAVA_HOME settings in my bash shell activate a profile?  Are you also suggesting I would have to create one different profile for each conceivable version of Java?

Comment: did you read about the `<activation>` of profiles? it is all explained in extreme detail.